# error returning information using php

Tags: php

I am steps away from finishing this project, I seem to have a problem with my logic in my fetchMessage() function, I am passing in the session_id however I am getting nothing returned here is my function code

```
function fetchMessages($session)
{
    $get = ("SELECT * FROM chatRoom WHERE session_id = '$session'");
    $hold = mysql_query($get, $con);

    if($hold)
    {
        return mysql_fetch_array($hold);
    }
}
```

the code calling this function is

```
<?php
include 'core/conection.php';
include 'function.php';

if(isset($_POST['method']) === true && empty($_POST['method']) === false)
{
    $method = trim($_POST['method']);
    $session = trim($_POST['session']);

    if($method === 'fetch')
    {
        $messages = fetchMessages($session);

        if(empty($messages) === true)
        {
            echo 'A representative will be with you shortly';
            echo '<br />';
            echo $session;
        }else
        {
            foreach($messages as $message)
            {
                $ts = $message['timestamp'];
                ?>
                <div class = "message">
                <?php echo date('n-j-Y h:i:s a', $ts); ?>
                <a href = "#"><?php echo $message['username']; ?></a>
                says:<p><?php echo nl2br($message['message']); ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I know it is making it at least this far because at this line

```
if(empty($messages) === true)
{
    echo 'A representative will be with you shortly';
    echo '<br />';
    echo $session;
}
```

it displays the correct session_id i have a fealing it is either my fetchMessages function that is wrong or the html code to display the results that is wrong.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and I hope you are not using this code in production.

Comment: $hold = mysql_query($get, $con); where is $con?

Comment: $con comes from the included connection file that creates the connection with my database @Aarolama Bluenk thank you for the links, I will get up to speed on them and begin using the new code

Comment: anyone have anything constructive to add here? is my code sound or do I have a syntax or logic error somewhere?

Comment: never mint everyone I have it figured out myself thanks for your time

Comment: @GraficRegret You have to enable error reporting to see what's wrong ... Also, you said that $con comes from the included connection file, but you're forgetting that when you call it in a function it will be in another scope, thus you have to use `global $con;` in your function